# Pasting from the clipboard and automatically toggling ":set paste"

Tags: vim, paste

When I paste things from the clipboard, they're normally (always) multilined, and in those cases (and those cases only), I'd like `:set paste` to be triggered, since otherwise the tabbing will increase with each line (you've all seen it!).

Though the problem with `:set paste` is that it doesn't behave well with `set smartindent`, causing the cursor to jump to the beginning of a new line instead of at the correct indent. So I'd like to enable it for this instance only.

I'm using Mac, sshing to a Debian machine with Vim, and thus pasting in Insert mode using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to migrate this question: not only are vim questions accepted as belonging on SO ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su ), it's a question about a programmer's text editor, being used to perform a task which is common when programming.

Comment: @Jefromi: Pasting is common when doing any form of text editing, but I'll concede that Vim/Emacs questions have been deemed acceptable for SO even when they aren't directly programming related.

@Jonatan: I'd highly recommend against using `'smartindent'`.  See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash#Using_filetype_indentation for an explanation as to why.

Comment: @jamessan: The point is that pasting with this specific formatting concern is a very, very common programming task. Nowhere else does one routinely paste blocks of text with indentation varying line-to-line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't use a mac, but I believe I have the prefix right here: `<D-v>` should mean cmd-v. For insert mode:

```
:imap <D-v> ^O:set paste<Enter>^R+^O:set nopaste<Enter>
```

or really, just do this:

```
:imap <D-V> ^O"+p
```

The ^O and ^R are literal control-O and control-R, which you can type with ^V^O (control-v control-o) and ^V^R (control-v control-r). Control-O in insert mode allows you to execute one command then return to insert mode; here you can use it to put from the clipboard register.

This worked for me when I tested them mapped to a different key, so you should be all set.

There's no need to map anything when not in insert mode; you can just use `"+p`.

Comment: Regarding `"+p`... depending on your operating system, you may need to change that to `"*p` . For my computer (osx) I needed to use the second version.

Answer (score 3):

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
inoremap <S-Insert> <ESC>:setl paste<CR>gi<C-R>+<ESC>:setl nopaste<CR>gi
```

`gi` is to start insert mode in the same position as where insert mode was stopped last time in the current buffer.

**Update:**

Jefromi posted a better solution. I have tinkered it a bit

```
inoremap <S-Insert> <ESC>"+p`]a
```

It inserts clipboard text and places the cursor right after it.

Comment: That's nice, but that only works on Shift-Insert, right? And that wouldn't work from my Mac, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: It could be easily mapped to whatever you prefer. <F5> for example.

Comment: @Jonatan Littke: My answer shows how to map this to command-v, and how to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that you should only enable `'paste'` when you need it.  It does more than just affect indenting.  You can read everything that it affects in its [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'paste').  A related option that is very useful to ease the use of `'paste'` is ['pastetoggle'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'pastetoggle').

If you were using X-forwarding and a terminal that can properly communicate mouse actions, you could also take advantage of the ['mouse'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'mouse') option.  With `:set mouse=a`, Vim is made aware of what the mouse is doing and therefore won't perform automatic indentation when it receives a multi-line paste via a middle-button mouse click.

Even without the mouse capability, X-forwarding could help because Vim will do the same thing when manually pasting from the clipboard or selection registers (`"+` and `"*` respectively).

Comment: Thanks.

I did ask for help getting X-forwarding and Mouse and what not to work (http://superuser.com/questions/98350/vim-and-mouse-with-ssh-from-mac-to-linux), but never got it all solved. 

I'll look into pastetoggle, that should solve it. Vim's documentation (and feature set) is really huge.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to be solvable with a Vim script. (I hate Vim scripting, so it would have to be a much more serious infliction to cause me to solve it myself.) Even with [iTerm2's "paste slowly" mode](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-hidden-settings.html), the default is to break the data to be pasted into 16 byte chunks and send one every 0.125 seconds. Therefore, you should be able to programmatically detect a 16 byte chunk of "keystrokes" and do something about it.

In pseudocode that would look like:

```py
if too_fast_too_be_human():
    set('pastemode', True)
else
    set('pastemode', False)

# where either
def too_fast_too_be_human
    char_threshold = 16
    return len(input_buffer) > char_threshold

# or
def too_fast_too_be_human
    static byte_times = []
    char_threshold = 16
    time_threshold = 0.125
    byte_times.append(now())
    while(len(byte_times) > char_threshold):
        byte_times.unshift()
    return (byte_times[-1] - byte_times[0]) < time_threshold
```

There are weaknesses to that, but it would work for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can paste (insert mode) without messing up indentation using

```
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o Register
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o +
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o *
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o 0
```

```
CTRL-R CTRL-O {0-9a-z"%#*+/:.-=}            *i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O*
Insert the contents of a register literally and don't
auto-indent.  Does the same as pasting with the mouse
"MiddleMouse". When the register is linewise this will
insert the text above the current line, like with `P`.
Does not replace characters!
The '.' register (last inserted text) is still inserted as
typed.
```